# using pusher npm in reactnative app

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get a basic reactnative app with chat feature going. Found a pusher npm on https://www.npmjs.com/package/pusher

Did install the module to the project with:

```
npm install pusher --save
```

As soon as I add to a react component following line of code

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');
```

the xcode project stops compiling with following stack trace:

```
bundle: Created ReactPackager
uncaught error Error: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module crypto from /Users/dmitry/hacks/tentags/TenTags/node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js: Invalid directory /Users/node_modules/crypto
    at ResolutionRequest.js:356:15
    at tryCallOne (/Users/dmitry/hacks/tentags/TenTags/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/dmitry/hacks/tentags/TenTags/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/Users/dmitry/hacks/tentags/TenTags/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
See logs /var/folders/gq/zxnwqjwd75d_2rhgbzzc_0n00000gn/T/react-packager.log
    at SocketClient._handleMessage (SocketClient.js:139:23)
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (SocketClient.js:53:42)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at BunserBuf.process (/Users/dmitry/hacks/tentags/TenTags/node_modules/bser/index.js:289:10)
    at /Users/dmitry/hacks/tentags/TenTags/node_modules/bser/index.js:244:12
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Is pusher npm only meant to work in react.js web apps? Can I not use pusher npm as is in ractnative app? I know, maybe naive questions, but I'm very new to reactnative and the whole JS, Node, npm business.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the library, filed it here: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-node/issues/23

Answer (score 0):

Do check you are in react's directory while installing.Have you made sure you have crypto, try installing pusher-js too... and use react-native

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';
```